# Can't understand lookup fields to retrieve data in Rest API

Tags: spfieldlookupvalue

I can't understand how to build Rest Query (SharePoint Api) to retrieve data from lookup fields. I've tried all that i read. I don't understand how to make right construct of Rest Query. All i've read didn't allow me to make any sence of it.

So, i have one lookup field in list named 'DocumentAuthor'.
This field looks to another list 'Organization'.
In 'Organization' list we have fields 'Title' or 'Id'.

This does not work:

```
/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxx-xxx-xxx...')/Items?$select=DocumentAuthor/Id&$expand=DocumentAuthor
```

Is returns that "value": `"Поле или свойство DocumentAuthor не существует."` (translation: `"Field or property DocumentAuthor does not exist."`).

I have tried this:

```
/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxx-xxx-xxx...')/Items?$select=DocumentAuthorId
```

... as i read in several sites, and this did not help me.

---

Here are some details about field, returned from rest api

```
{
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "http://---/_api/Web/Lists(guid'---')/Fields(guid'---')",
            "uri": "http://---/_api/Web/Lists(guid'---')/Fields(guid'---')",
            "type": "SP.FieldLookup"
        },
        "CanBeDeleted": true,
        "DefaultValue": null,
        "Description": "",
        "Direction": "none",
        "EnforceUniqueValues": false,
        "EntityPropertyName": "DocumentAuthor",
        "Filterable": true,
        "FromBaseType": false,
        "Group": "Базовые для документа",
        "Hidden": false,
        "Id": "---",
        "Indexed": false,
        "InternalName": "DocumentAuthor",
        "JSLink": "",
        "ReadOnlyField": false,
        "Required": false,
        "SchemaXml": ",
        "Scope": "/Lists/DocumentsLibrary",
        "Sealed": false,
        "Sortable": false,
        "StaticName": "DocumentAuthor",
        "Title": "Автор документа",
        "FieldTypeKind": 0,
        "TypeAsString": "OrganizationStructureItemsPickerField",
        "TypeDisplayName": "Выбор пользователей из структуры предприятия",
        "TypeShortDescription": "Выбор пользователей из структуры предприятия",
        "ValidationFormula": null,
        "ValidationMessage": null,
        "AllowMultipleValues": true,
        "IsRelationship": true,
        "LookupField": "Title",
        "LookupList": "{zzz}",
        "LookupWebId": "fff",
        "PrimaryFieldId": null,
        "RelationshipDeleteBehavior": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listName')/items?$select=DocumentAuthor/ID,DocumentAuthor/Title&$expand=DocumentAuthor/ID
```

Comment: Please add some details to let the OP understand how can use the lookup in REST, Thanks!

Comment: The same error (Field... does not exist)

Comment: Please check the internal name of the field used in the rest query is same.

Comment: How to check it? As I mentioned higher it is same                  
       "InternalName": "DocumentAuthor"

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing right. The `$expand` parameter is used to retrieve field from a lookup ones, then you need to specify fields you want with the `$select` parameter.

Does

```
/_api/Web/lists(guid'XXXX')/Items?$select=DocumentAuthor
```

returns something else than `Field or property DocumentAuthor does not exist.` ?

Comment: The value of \"DocumentAuthor\" field cannot be serialized with \"OrganizationStructureItemsPickerField\" type" (original: "Значение поля \"DocumentAuthor\" с типом \"OrganizationStructureItemsPickerField\" не может быть сериализовано.")

Comment: Can you translate it please ?

Comment: The value of \"DocumentAuthor\" field cannot be serialized with \"OrganizationStructureItemsPickerField\" type" (when I want to put Enter it submitting my Comment :)

Comment: No problem. :) If you try to query a single item, do you see this field in results ?

Comment: No! I don't. Error "Field or property DocumentAuthor does not exist."

Comment: Are you sure to use the right guid ? Because you say your column is in `DocumentAuthor` list but seems to be in `DocumentsLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an expand on the display name instead of static name? If I remember correctly, some SharePoint versions use the display name in REST API.